# Can't overwrite js filed in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, template, overrides

I tried to overwrite `**date.js(module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element)**` and `**range.js (module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/filters)**`in my custom theme but it's not working. it not take me the changes form this files, even i found in **pub** folder in the **module-ui** folder, those 2 files are modified, but the effect not applied. if i try to modify in vendor, i can see the changes.

To overwirte this 2 files, in my custom theme i use this path:

> app\design\frontend\Medipoin\mytheme\Magento_Ui\web\js\form\element (date.js)

and

> app\design\frontend\Medipoin\mytheme\Magento_Ui\web\js\grid\filters (range.js)

I also clear the cache and flush.

Does anyone know why i can't overwirte this files?

Comment: Try deploying once and **clear your browser cache**.

Comment: Please run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and clear cache and remove var folder from root plus clear browser cache.